# Ejecutar operacion matematica de un string y retorne el resultado

Tags: javascript

He tratado de realizarlo pero no encuentro como hacerlo, en determinado momento del código JavaScript obtengo un string del tipo `(4+5)/2` y quiero obtener esta operación.

Trate usando `parseFloat` no reconoce los símbolos como el `+` o `(` por lo que me dice que eso no es un número.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes construir una función que te evalue cada elemento de tu string. Por si solo parseFloat solo parse a números.

```js
function evaluaArimetica(fn) {
 return new Function('return ' + fn)();
}
console.log( evaluaArimetica('12/5*9+9.4*2') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar la funcion [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval) de JavaScript.

```js
alert(eval("(4+5)/2"))
```

Comment: si usas esta opcion ten en cuenta lo que dice mozilla developer  **es una función peligrosa, quel ejecuta el código el cual es pasado con los privilegios de quien llama.  Si ejecuta eval() con una cadena de carcteres que podría ser afectada por un elemento malicioso, podría terminar ejecutando código malicioso dentro de la computadora del usuario con los permisos de su página o extensión web .**

Comment: @JackNavaRow, esta opción como la de [Aaron](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125119/16597), tiene el mismo problema de seguridad. [Mas info aquí](http://2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html)

Comment: excelente informacion @Marcos entonces es mejor hacerlo a la vieja escuela split char i is_digit

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la function **eval()**

> La función eval() evalúa un código JavaScript representado como una cadena de caracteres (string), sin referenciar a un objeto en particular.

**Sintaxis**

```
eval(cadena de caracteres o string)
```

**Parámetros**

> cadena de caracteres (string)
>   Una cadena de caracteres (string) que representa una expresión, sentencia o secuencia de sentencias en JavaScript. La expresión puede incluir variables y propiedades de objetos existentes.

**Valores retornados o devueltos**

> El valor que resulta de la evaluación del código proporcionado. Si este valor está vacío. undefined (artículo en inglés) es devuelto.

```js
console.log(eval("(4+5)/2"))
```

**No utilice eval innecesariamente**

> eval() es una función peligrosa, quel ejecuta el código el cual es pasado con los privilegios de quien llama.  Si ejecuta eval() con una cadena de carcteres que podría ser afectada por un elemento malicioso, podría terminar ejecutando código malicioso dentro de la computadora del usuario con los permisos de su página o extensión web . Más importante aún, una parte del código de terceros podría accesar al ámbito en el cual eval() fue invocada, lo que puede permitir la entrada a posibles ataques de formas a las que el constructor Function (art. en inglés) el cual es similar, no es susceptible.
>
> eval() es generalmente también más lenta que otras alternativas desde que se invoca en el intérprte de JS, mientras que otros muchos constructores son optimizados por los motores JS modernos.

Espero te ayude saludos.

fuente : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval)